# updating pandas dataframe via for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas, dataframe

I have a bunch of URLs stored into a data frame and I am cleaning them up via a url parsing module.  The issue that I am having is that the 'siteClean' field that is supposed to update with the cleaned url is updating the entire column and not the individual cell...

Here is the code:

```
results = resultsX.copy(deep = True)
results = results.reset_index(drop = True)
results['siteClean'] = ''


from urlparse import urlsplit  
import re

for row in results.iterrows():
    #print row[1]
    url = row[1][1]
    if not re.match(r'http(s?)\:', url):
        url = 'http://' + url
    parsed = urlsplit(url)
    host = parsed.netloc
    #print host
    #row[1][1] = host
    #results[row][1] = host
    results['siteClean'] = host
    print results
```

Comment: `results['siteClean']` returns a series on your dataframe which is why it updates the entire column, it would be better to build your clean list first and create a dataframe from it

Comment: yeah i realized that and that is probably the best solution to get this project done and out... but is there a way to update the dataframe within the for loop?

Comment: You will need to [index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) properly, is this a pre-existing dataframe or are you populating and creating from scratch, you can index using integer or label based, if you were doing this from scratch then you would need to keep track of the row number as you append each entry so something like `results.iloc[row]['siteClean']=host` or similar. Still it will be much simpler and easier to understand if you populated the list first, if you have a lot of urls though then it could be slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it's better to avoid looping over your frame's rows, if you can avoid it.  If I understand your problem correctly, you want to look at a single column from your frame, and apply a function on each element of that column.  Then you want to put the result of all those function calls into a column of the original frame.  Maybe a new column, maybe in place of the old column.  This sounds like a job for `pd.Series.map`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

n=10

df = pd.DataFrame({'num': np.random.randn(n),
                   'lett': np.random.choice(
                        list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),n)
                   })
```

`df` looks like this:

[image: df original]

Set up a function to classify a single letter as either a consonant or a vowel:

```
def classify_letter(char):
    if char in list('aeiou'):
        return 'vowel'
    else:
        return 'consonant'
```

Then you can use `map` to generate a new `Series` whose entries are those of the input transformed by the specified function.  You can stick that new output series wherever you like.  It can be a new column (in your old `DataFrame` or elsewhere) or it can replace the old column.  Note that `map` only works on a `Series`, so be sure to select down to one column before using it:

```
df['new'] = df['lett'].map(classify_letter)
```

gives:

[image: df with col added]

while if you started from the original setup and ran:

```
df['lett'] = df['lett'].map(classify_letter)
```

then you would replace the old column with the new one:

[image: df with col replaced]